# Search data in asp.net web api and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I want to find a name records
For example i have two record

```
<Employee>
<Name>Jone</Name>
<Address>United Kingdom</Address>
<Phone>0123456789</Phone>
</Employee>
------------------
<Employee>
<Name>Ronaldo</Name>
<Address>Portugal</Address>
<Phone>0123456789</Phone>
</Employee>
```

i'd like for example implement:

```
http://localhost:18179/Api/Employee/Search/ronal
```

`ronal` is string from keyboard. Result

```
<Employee>
<Name>Ronaldo</Name>
<Address>Portugal</Address>
<Phone>0123456789</Phone>
</Employee>
```

I tried to but not ok.

```
public List<Employee> SearchList(string name)
        {
            var store = db.Employyes.Where(a => a.Name.Contains(name)).ToList();
            return store;
        }
```

Comment: My english not good, sr

Comment: Why is it not OK?

Comment: <Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:18179/Api/Employee/Search/ronal'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No action was found on the controller 'Employee' that matches the request.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

Comment: in controller my function name is Search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a route using, for example, [HttpGet] and [Route]:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("search/{name}")]
public List<Employee> Search(string name)
{
}
```

Comment: [HttpGet]
        [Route("search/{name}")]
        public IEnumerable<Store> Search(string name)
        {
            return storeManager.SearchList(name);
        }